# Asyncio Socket Not Reading Data Sent on Socket after Working Initially

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

I'm running into a somewhat perplexing problem in my setup and I'm not sure if it's because I'm doing something wrong with the asyncio socket primitives or there's a deeper issue with my networking setup.

Basically, I have a server (call it `sleep-server`) that instantiates a long lived TCP socket connection with another server (call it `beacon-server`). This is done using `asyncio.open_connection`:

```
beacon_reader, beacon_writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
    beacon_server_endpoint.ip, BEACON_PORT)
```

The long lived connection is kicked off with an initial request/response to the `beacon` server. Here's that code:

```
beacon_writer.write(request)
await beacon_writer.drain()

# Read the beacon server's response
try:
    beacon_response = await asyncio.wait_for(beacon_reader.read(4096), timeout=10)
except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
    print('Timed out waiting for beacon server sleep response')
    raise SleepRequestError(e)

# Do some stuff with the response data
```

This works completely fine and well. After that, the application enters a flow where it periodically writes TCP data to the Beacon server on the same socket:

```
while True:
    data = method_that_gets_some_data()
    beacon_writer.write(data)
    await beacon_writer.drain()
```

This also works completely fine. The beacon server receives its data and does what it needs to do. During this stage, the beacon server does not write anything back on the socket.

It's only when I try to receive data from the beacon server socket again that things go wrong. Basically, via a separate mechanism the beacon server is told to fetch the existing socket (the one that is currently being written to by the sleep server) and send a message down to it. For business reasons, the beacon server manages its socket connections using gevent and Python's built in socket library, but it's the same stuff, and based on the above flow we already know it works. Here's the code for sending a message back down onto the socket:

```
# client.connection is just a python Socket object

client.connection.setblocking(0)
client.connection.send(client.wake_up_secret.decode('hex'))
print('sending client shutdown')
client.connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
```

And here's the code on the other server that receives this message:

```
data = beacon_reader.read()
```

Based on some logging I can see that the Beacon server is properly performing the `send()` to the socket. I also see that the `sleep-server` is getting to the code where it runs `beacon_reader.read()`. However, the sleep server just blocks there even after the Beacon server has sent down its packet. I've tried playing around with the size paramater in the `read()` command, even setting it as low as `2` just to see if I could get anything off the socket, but there's nothing. I've also tried removing the `connection.shutdown()`, which doesn't seem to help either.

What's baffling is clearly it worked before since I was able to get an initial response, and clearly it's tied to the correct socket since the beacon_writer is functioning with no problems. So I'm curious if I'm just doing something stupid with the underlying asyncio library or something.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `data = await beacon_reader.read()`?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I understand that will just dictate whether it will yield control in the event loop before the IO completes. In other words, without it, it will still work but nothing else can happen concurrently. I tried adding it back in, and still have the same problem.

Comment: Since `StreamReader.read` is [a coroutine](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fc40b3020cf3c869833fd5d3720cf9768fe3bb46/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#L624), not awaiting it makes it pretty much a no-op - unless you're saying that you just await it later. Another thing: later in the question you say that the sleep-server "just blocks". Have you tried adding prints to see where it block - at which await?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that not awaiting it would render it a no-op. I figured it would behave the same as a generator method that doesn't `yield` -- it would just keep executing until it hit another yield. To answer your question re blocking, I have a print statement right before the `beacon_reader.read()`, and again right after. It prints the initial statement but never hits the subsequent one. That's both with and without the `await`.

Comment: In the generator analogy, calling an async method and not awaiting it is sort of like calling a generator and not exhausting it. Just calling a generator function doesn't run any of its code, not even up to the first `yield`.

Comment: *It prints the initial statement but never hits the subsequent one. That's both with and without the await* - Something extremely strange is going on there. What is `type(beacon_reader)`? What version of Python do you use?

Comment: It’s an asyncio.streams.StreamReader — Python 3.7.9

Comment: And you literally have `print("foo"); beacon_reader.read(); print("bar")` (so no await in front of `read()`), and `foo` is printed but `bar` isn't?

Comment: Yep, and it’s the same if I add an await

Comment: Could you try running your `sleep-server` with `python -W ignore sleep-server`?

Comment: Just tried that. The only difference is that if I don’t have “await,” it eventually complains about an AttributeError, coroutine has no attribute “decode.” Which makes sense. However, that error only surfaces if I start another session which spins up a new coroutine. With the “await,” it’s just the usual silence.

Comment: I just figured it out. The data was coming in fine, but my print statement was calling decode() on the bytes when it should have called hex(). For some reason, rather than output the exception it raised, it swallowed it until a new coroutine was initiated. Is there a reason errors in coroutines get buffered like this?

Comment: Glad it's settled. The exceptions are not buffered by asyncio, you probably have an architectural issue where you spawn a task to run in the background without ensuring that someone catches the exceptions it raises. The exception then gets stuck as part of the "result" of the task object which you never pick up, and Python only reports it when it notices that the task object gets GC'ed without the exception having ever been retrieved. The fix is to ensure that each task has someone that will notice and propagate (or handle) an exception happening in it.